# Index Python fetchall()

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to use Python with MySQL. I'm having trouble addressing entries in the query results.

So if I do something like this:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.178.10",
                     user="user",
                     passwd="password",
                     db="testdb")

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from Persons;")
print(cur.fetchall()[2][2])


db.close()
```

I get the third entry of the third row which seems plausible.

If I do this:

```
print(cur.fetchall()[0][0:2])
```

I get the first to entries of the first row. Which also seems plausible.

However if I do something like this:

```
print(cur.fetchall()[0:2][2])
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(cur.fetchall()[0:2][2])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Which I do not understand.

Also I am unable to get (for example) all the first entries of all the rows. To achieve this it seems I need to do a loop through the entries I want.

Could someone clarify what I'm doing wrong or how this works?

Greetings!

Comment: bucause this slice `cur.fetchall()[0:2]`  just has index 0 and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, without a specified ordering you do not get "third row" with

```
cur.execute("select * from Persons;")
print(cur.fetchall()[2][2])
```

You get a random row. It may seem stable enough, but do not trust it.

The reason you get `IndexError: tuple index out of range` is that with

```
print(cur.fetchall()[0:2][2])
```

you take a slice of elements from 0 to 1 from the result set and then you try to take the 3rd element with `[2]`, which does not exist, since your slice had 2 elements.

E.g.

```
In [1]: rows = tuple(zip(range(10), range(10)))

In [2]: rows
Out[2]: 
((0, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 4),
 (5, 5),
 (6, 6),
 (7, 7),
 (8, 8),
 (9, 9))

In [3]: rows[0:2]
Out[3]: ((0, 0), (1, 1))

In [4]: rows[0:2][0]
Out[4]: (0, 0)

In [5]: rows[0:2][2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2b13f1394ba3> in <module>()
----> 1 rows[0:2][2]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

To actually take the 3rd attribute from the result tuples you can use for example a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) or a list comprehension:

```
In [6]: rows = tuple(zip(range(10), range(10), range(10,20)))

In [7]: [r[2] for r in rows[0:2]]
Out[7]: [10, 11]
```

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify it. I would still like to know if there is a way of addressing all the entries in a certain column except for looping through them an writing them into a list?

Comment: "select the_column from Persons" to begin with, if you only need that, or use `map` (in python3) or a generator expression, if you don't want to generate a list (with list comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

A tuple of list elements when queried with range of indexes returns another set of tuple with list of elements.

```
>>> t = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],)
>>> print( t[0:2] ) # 2 is number of lists in the resulting tuple
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Here you can observe that resulting tuple size is 2 elements. And indexes can be 0 and 1 only. Hence following statement fails.

```
>>> print( t[0:2][2] ) # [2] is pointing to non existing index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>>
```

Correct statement can be this.

```
>>> print( t[0:2][1] )
[4, 5, 6]
```

If I understand correct, your intention is to find 2nd column value from first 2 rows from the dataset fetched. Possible statement can be:

```
>>> for x in t[0:2]: print (x)
...
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
>>>
>>> for x in t[0:2]: print (x[2])
...
3
6
>>>
```

Hence, the statement

```
print(cur.fetchall()[0:2][2])
```

can be re-written as:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()[ 0:2 ]
for row in rows: print ( row[ 2 ] )
```